# Проблема с отображением картинок

Tags: python, html, css, flask

Скажите пожалуйста как сделать. Недавно начал работать с бэком(Python + flask) еще не знаю

изначальная проблемы была таковой, что сайт не отображал не стили не картинки
для решения стилей мне дали такое решение
`<link ... href="{{url_for('static', filename= 'style.css')}}">`

Я решил что для картинок решение будет таким же. Но столкнулся с проблемой с css
Дело в том что все изображения поставлены на фон элементов через background: url(--);
конечно же css не понимает фигурных скобок такого формата

Подскажите пожалуйста как работать с картинками

Comment: вы можете использовать в css относительные пути

Comment: т.е. путь изображения относительно файла со стилями. Браузер сам вычислит абсолютный путь.

Comment: да боже если бы вычислял то он бы не выдавал 404 не найдено. Бэк работает по другому

Comment: когда я набросал фронт, в браузере все работало

Comment: давайте без "да боже". Приложите фактическое значение которое указано в CSS, ссылка которая генерируется на стили в верстке и адрес по которому успешно отображаются стили, и где лежат стили и изображения в проекте...

Comment: избитая фраза, но тут нет экстрасенсов и просто гадать времени нет.

Answer (score -1):

Во первых:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
```

Во вторых не:

```
background: url('')
```

, а:

```
background-image: url('')
```

---

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то это поможет.